# Model Mesh Breaks

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm not sure of the terminology, what do you call it when this happens? This has been happening to me a lot.

Is it the limitations of the hardware? Which is a firepro v5900 2gb.

I'm planning on upgrading the gpu. Could that fix the issue?[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. It would help if you post screenshots of the whole Blender window so we can see the outliner, number of objects, and modifiers, and so on. Does your model has a MultiRes modifier? I've experienced similar issues when the base mesh was edited with a MultiRes.

Comment: About the terminology: It's the mesh that is messed up here. The material defines the shader (texture, color, etc).

Comment: I added screenshots. And well, I said material that because in this case the mesh breaks when I add a material to the eye and jacket.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. It makes sense that you said material when the material makes the mesh "explode". But this is not normal behavior. If you want you can share the blend file here https://pasteall.org/blend/ (after upload you need to post here the new URL that you get in the browser's address bar). How does the mesh look ok when you render it with Cycles on the CPU?